# The best method for filling char array (gets vs cin.getline)

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using C ++ 11. I'm wondering if there are any advantages to using `cin.getline ()` compared to `gets ()`.

I need to fill a `char` array.

Also, should I use `fgets` or `getline` for files?

Comment: Why are you using a `char` array for reading into in C++?

Comment: If you want to read a line into a string, then use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  It was deprecated and has since been removed from C++ (also C)

Comment: @UnholySheep I just started to study c ++, so now at my university we are mainly explained on char array. String is so much better?

Comment: @DenAndreychuk Yes, `std::string` is much better.  It manages the memory for you.  There might be uses cases when you don't need it but that's something you'll find out when you profile the code.

Answer (score 8):

> I'm wondering if there are any advantages to using cin.getline () compared to gets ().

I am assuming you really mean `gets`, not `fgets`.

Yes, there definitely is. `gets` is known to be a security problem. `cin.getline()` does not suffer from that problem.

It's worth comparing `fgets` and `cin.getline`.

The only difference that I see is that `fgets` will include the newline character in the output while `cin.getline` won't.

Most of the time, the newline character is ignored by application code. Hence, it is better to use `cin.getline()` or `istream::getline()` in general. If presence of the newline character in the output is important to you for some reason, you should use `fgets`.

Another reason to prefer `istream::getline` is that you can specify a character for the delimiter. If you need to parse a comma separated values (CSV) file, you can use:

```
std::ifstream fstr("some file name.csv");
fstr.getline(data, data_size, ',');
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just put the newline back in the output than change to old-style i/o?

Comment: @Galik, it's a judgement call. My rationale was - why add more code in client code when there is a standard library function that already does that?

Answer (score 3):

Of course.
First of all `gets` doesn't check of length of the input - so if the input if longer than char array, you are getting an overflow.
On the other hand `cin.getline` allows to specify the size of stream.
Anyway, the consensus among C++ programmers is that you should avoid raw arrays anyway.